# Unable to delete Storage Account : Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I have a storage account in my Azure sub which I am trying to delete. When I try to do so, it says I have a storage account in my Azure which I cant delete. When I try to delete that it says

```
Failed to delete storage account <storage acc name>. Error: An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access.
```

I have tried multiple times, even after waiting, but nothing is working. Any solution?

Comment: Working over a similar issue. Will update this thread with resolutions as found.

Comment: Is it empty or not? Because, if you are trying to delete storage full of content it will throw a similar error. Clean it before deleting.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

- Login as (or ask your) global admin and attempt to delete the storage account
- Unlikely but if the above fails ask Global Administrator add themselves as a Storage Blob Data Owner and then try to delete the Storage Account.
- Remove Resource Lock
- In my case Microsoft support are attempting to delete the storage account. All other workflows failed. Will post RCA when isolated. Note this is using Professional Direct support contract.

For reference I logged into the Azure portal with an account with no support contract to test your condition. I was able to create a support ticket but with a very limited set of options, under the TECHNICAL heading, only AZURE INFORMATION PROTECTION option was available for example.

[image]

My storage account deletion issue has highlighted an error condition exists where a Global Admin user is unable to delete a storage resource containing no data or resource lock. In this case Microsoft are actioning the removal of the problem resource following several weeks of calls , threads and remote sessions.

I suggest you attempt to raise a ticket via any means , highlight your issue and hopefully Microsoft will internally route the issue to the correct department.

**Root Cause Analysis**

- An operation to delete the storage account was never finished Azure side.
- Every operation holds a lock on the storage account to prevent conflicts between different operations.
- In my case the lock prevented all other operations we performed: deleting, updating, deploying etc.

Microsoft are yet to detect which operation exactly was causing the issue but explained similar issues when another user tried to modify the tag of a storage account with misused escape characters.

In my case its likely that a DevOps pipeline was modifying the storage account, the request to Azure Resource Management(ARM) was somehow incomplete due to, for example, a network fluctuation / transient error.

**Resolution**

The way to resolve the issue is Microsoft manually reset the status of the lock on the storage account and release the lock form the storage account. Delete operations are then possible.  Microsoft are taking steps to improve the process.

Answer (score 0):

Was your storage Account Encrypted?
Was your storage Account used as a VDI Blob storage ?

Thanks and regards,
Abdel

Comment: I never used it, thats the case. I created it for testing purpose